# Learning "The Art of Prolog"

Tags: prolog

To those of you familiar with "The Art of Prolog", which software tools (e.g. IDEs, editors, compilers, etc.) would you suggest for following the book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SWI-Prolog](http://swi-prolog.org) is a free Prolog implementation that comes with an integrated editor (an Emacs clone written in Prolog) and graphical debugger and profiler.

Comment: and what about Visual Prolog? I've just downloaded it, but the interface is not very impressive.

Comment: @Sergey: VisualProlog is not free, only runs on Windows, and does not follow the Prolog ISO standard so probably, it is not the best option to learn Prolog as a companion for "The Art of Prolog".

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go for SWI-Prolog, I would suggest to use PDT (The Prolog Development Tool), that is a Prolog IDE. It also works for the multi-paradigm language Logtalk that uses Prolog implementation as back end compilers.

You can find PDT [here](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start)